# I cannot redirect output to file

Tags: sh, io-redirection, busybox, lirc

I use specific program named lirc_monitor is used to monitoring pressed keys on the embedded ARM device. I wanna redirect all output to file but I'm stuck I spended ~2 hours to check every option what I found and... nothing! file all the time empty..

Maybe someone has any ideas? to verify this problem. Thank you.

```
-sh-3.2# lirc_monitor 
{lirc monitor}: 0000000000000000 00 CURSOR_DOWN MTK_IR

{lirc monitor}: 0000000000000000 00 CURSOR_DOWN MTK_IR

{lirc monitor}: 0000000000000000 00 CURSOR_DOWN MTK_IR

{lirc monitor}: 0000000000000000 00 CURSOR_DOWN MTK_IR

{lirc monitor}: 0000000000000000 00 CURSOR_DOWN MTK_IR

{lirc monitor}: 0000000000000000 00 CURSOR_DOWN MTK_IR
```

Comment: Have you tested `lirc_monitor > log 2>&1` ?

Comment: Yep still empty.

Comment: You made sure that you have permission to write to the file?

Comment: Yes ofc I'm root and save to /tmp.

Comment: Related Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002223/lirc-monitor-how-to-track-process-data-output-in-loop

Comment: perhaps it's using `wall` or directly writing to your terminal from another process

Comment: Can I do something about it?

Comment: Can you please clarify how this is different from your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76002223/lirc-monitor-how-to-track-process-data-output-in-loop?

Comment: No, that's the origin of the problem, I'm trying to find the cause. Script from this thread not working like should be.

Comment: Ok I got help on russian forum this is translation "PS: I got burned and I made a smarter patch - now lirc_monitor clears buffers after each line by calling fflush(). Patched lirc_monitor_fflush, which can be parsed normally with a pipe:" So I got patched binary file and I can without any problems redirect to log.

Answer (score 0):

lirc_monitor normally outputs to stderr rather than stdout, so you need `2>` to redirect its output.  Eg:

```
lirc_monitor 2> lirc_monitor.log
```

Comment: In this case I see output in console after pressed button but file empty https://i.imgur.com/9E7Zner.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got help on russian forum this is translation:

"PS: I got burned and I made a smarter patch - now lirc_monitor clears buffers after each line by calling fflush(). Patched lirc_monitor_fflush, which can be parsed normally with a pipe:"

So I got patched binary file and I can without any problems redirect to log.

Problem resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect the output stream with `>`

```bash
lirc_monitor > output.log
```

For more convenience, use `tee`, which will write to *both* the file and [`stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))

```bash
lirc_monitor | tee -a output.log
```

---

If `>` doesn't redirect the output (you still see the output with simply `>`), it's going to [`stderr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)), and you can redirect it with `2> filename` directly or `2>&1`  to join the `stderr` to `stdout` stream

```bash
lirc_monitor 2>&1 | tee -a output.log
```

Comment: I tried still empty.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the using nohup

```bash
nohup lrc_monitor > lrc_monitor.log &
```

`nohup` - ignores hang up, probably needed because lrc_monitor seem to keep running until you stop it manually.

`> lrc_monitor.log` - tells the terminal to log the output to a file called `lrc_monitor.log`

`&` - tells the terminal to run your command in the background

Comment: Still empty :(  https://i.imgur.com/rU3NIa6.png

Comment: try `cat /tmp/dupa.log` to see contents of the log file? your command line output shows it's running under PID 3640

Comment: Ofc I check log file ;)